# Redirecting to wrong URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

I've been working on a website and have made some changes to my .htaccess file recently. Whenever I went to localhost/company it redirected me correctly, but now whenever I go to localhost/company it redirects me to http://localhost/company.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php// with a 404 page error, so obviously that page doesn't exist. It redirects me to the wrong URL.

I am pretty sure the issue comes from my .htaccess file, I've rolled back .htaccess from 3 months ago and this issue still occurs.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^config\.php - [R=404,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^i(/.*)?/company /company [L,NC]


# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh|svn|7z|zip|rar|gz|tar)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: When you remove, or comment out the htaccess file does the redirection stop?

Comment: No @mayersdesign

Comment: Is this your most recent `.htaccess` file? If you've "rolled back .htaccess from 3 months ago" then you may just be seeing a cached redirect?

Comment: Then I assume you have a cached page. To double check write some gibberish at the top of the htaccess and reload... you should get an error

Comment: This is my most recent .htaccess file, yes. I've rolled back and the issue is still not fixed.

Comment: Does `company.php` exist as a physical file? If it doesn't exist (eg. it's been deleted) then you will get the redirect loop you are seeing.

Comment: Well, it has been deleted and restored a couple of times. @w3dk

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you will likely get this redirect loop if `contact.php` does not exist.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^config\.php - [R=404,L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
> ```

Try changing these first few lines to (assuming this `.htaccess` file is in the document root):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^config\.php - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

This simply checks first that the file would exist, before rewriting. I've also added the `L` (`last`) to both these directives - I can't see that any later rules depend on these?